# Why is zIndex not working from IE/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, z-index

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
        <title>Problem demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="background:red; position:relative;" id='div1'>1.
            <div style="background:lime; position: absolute; width: 300px;height: 300px; top: 3px; left: 30px" id="div3">3.</div>
        </div>
        <div style="background:blue;position:relative;color: white" id="div2">2.</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/
            window.onload= function()
            {
                // The container of the absolute DIV
                document.getElementById('div1').style.zIndex = 800;

                // The lowest DIV of all which obscures the absolute DIV
                document.getElementById('div2').style.zIndex = 1;

                // The absolute DIV
                document.getElementById('div3').style.zIndex = 1000;
            }
        /*]]>*/</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In a nutshell, this script has two `DIV` elements with `position:relative` and the first of them has a third `DIV` with `position:absolute` in it. It's all set to run on IE-7 standards mode (I'm targeting IE7 and above).

I know about the separate z-stacks of IE, so by default the third `DIV` should be beneath the second `DIV`. To fix this problem there is some Javascript which sets the z-orders of first and third `DIV` to 1000, and the z-order of the second `DIV` to 999.

Unfortunately this does not help. If the z-indexes were set in markup, this would work, but why not from JS?

**Note:** This problem does not exist in IE8 standards mode, but I'm targetting IE7, so I can't rely on that. Also, if you save this to your hard drive and then open it up, at first IE complains something about ActiveX and stuff. After you wave it away, everything works as expected. But if you refresh the page, the problem is there again.

**Added:** Actually, you can reduce it even further to just

```
window.onload= function()
{
    document.getElementById('div1').style.zIndex = 800;
}
```

And the problem is still there.

Comment: That "ActiveX and stuff" complaint (Information Bar) means that your JavaScript code didn't run either. Hence, if you were expecting it to, that's your problem right there.

Comment: @EricLaw - I'm not *that* stupid. Let me rephrase. When IE prompts `To help protect your security, Internet Explorer has restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls that could access your computer. Click here for options...`, you should click it and select `Allow Blocked Content...`. After that you should refresh the page (you will not be prompted again) and the bug will be observable.

Answer (score 0):

**div2** is `absolute` within a `relative` element, that relative element **div1** has the same zIndex as the relative **div3** element. I think that IE might pick the relative zIndex of **div1** (and the fact that it comes before **div3**) to help put the `absolute` element over **div3**, simply because **div1** is "higher" than **div3**..

I don't have IE7 at hand to actually test your code right now, but maybe if you try with easier zIndex values, and all different? Like "100, 200, 300" for div1, etc. (respectively), that way **div3** should be above **div1**, thus **div2**.

*god that sounds like a load of gibberish when I read it back, but hopefully it helps*

(added, from my comment below) change the `overflow` value of those 3 div elements to `visible` and it works. It sounds strange, but that's IE; strange.

Comment: I think you mixed up the numbering. :) div1 and div2 are relative; div3 is absolute and within div1.

Comment: Sh*t. Fixing! :D There, that should do it. This is what I meant.

Comment: Well if no one else solves it before I am within a IE7 test machine I'll take another gander at it. Right now I ran out of ideas if this doesn't work.

Comment: @Vilx try setting "overflow" to visible for all 3 divs with Javascript before setting the zIndex. (added) this sounds silly but hey, it's IE we're talking about. It seemed to work in my little test case based on your code.

Comment: Actually, I found that setting `zoom:1` also helps, even if done through CSS and not Javascript. I have a suspicion that this has to do with the infamous `hasLayout`...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure from what you stated that you already know this but IE7 generates a new stacking context on positioned elements so z-index doesn't work as it should in IE<8. I don't recall the fix, and I'm not sure it applies here, but Google around for that.

[This appears to be a helpful article.](http://richa.avasthi.name/blogs/tepumpkin/2008/01/11/ie7-lessons-learned/)

Comment: No, this is not the case. I already said I know about this, and the example above should work with this in mind as well.